# For CUDA, does a thread stay on a single SP on GPU?

Tags: cuda, scheduling

When programming CUDA, we all know that a thread block will be scheduled on a SM and will not migrate to other SMs. As for a thread of a thread block, will it stay on a single SP throughout its execution, or its instructions could be scheduled on different SPs arbitrarily?

Comment: SP is a somewhat obscure reference to Scalar Processor, used in some NVIDIA presentation material (such as slides 8, 9 [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Webinars_CUDA_Memory_Optimization.pdf)) to refer to a CUDA "core", which is widely used in NVIDIA documentation, albeit a slightly general term.  CUDA core refers to the execution unit(s) associated with the processing of a single thread.  Core is somewhat general, since, depending on the instruction, the execution of it may occur in different functional units within the SM/SMX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The programming model does not restrict a thread to a single CUDA core. A thread block must execute on a single SM since threads within a block can communicate through shared memory and shared memory is only accessible by threads within the same SM. That restriction is part of what allows GPUs to scale from mobile to supercomputing.

Why is it helpful to know whether a thread executes on a single CUDA core? The CUDA model is for throughput computing, which means that when one thread (warp) is doing an operation with some latency the hardware can instantly bring in another thread (warp) to fill the gap. As a result it shouldn't matter where any given thread is executing.

Comment: Thanks, Tom! Your answer is very helpful. For a programmer, it is actually not necessary to know that. Just out of curiosity, maybe I want to write a simulator someday, lol.

Answer (score 3):

A CUDA core is a pipelined execution unit capable of executing single precision and integer instructions. Common other names for a CUDA core would be an ALU, math datapath, data pipeline, ... The CUDA core is the execution and write back stage of the SM.

CUDA cores are one of several types of execution units in an SM. Others include the Load Store Units (LSU), Branch Units, Double Precision Units, and Special Function Units.

EDIT:

A CUDA core does not manage threads/warps. The front end fetches instructions, decodes the instructions, reads the registers and dispatches (issues) the warp (instruction+registers) to a FP/INT execution unit core) or one of other types of execution units.

Think of a CUDA core as a classic microprocessor pipelined execution unit (ADU, ALU, AVX, ...).

Comment: Thanks, Greg. Your answer reveals some details of a CUDA core of SM, however, it doesn't tell me what I need. As we know, there is a 'pipeline' thing between warps, namely, when one warp encounters some long latency instruction, other warps will be scheduled to hide this latency. Thus does this 'pipeline' have some relationship with the traditional pipeline within a CUDA core you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to restrict one thread on one fixed SP, and I believe it is easy and efficient to freely issue threads to any SP in a fixed group of SPs(I mean, one SM may be divided to different blocks to ease the design and minimize inter-connection).

Comment: Your answer corrects one of my fallacies. Thank you, Xiaolong!